# Does it matter where your shots land in Planetside 2?

Tags: planetside-2

I know there is a word for this but I just can't recall. What I'm asking is "is hitting someone on the head going to kill them faster than shooting only their legs/torso (like some games) or is it the same damage wherever I shoot (like some others)?".

Comment: Welcome to the game by the way! Thanks for posting all these questions, they're of good use to others.

Comment: Thanks MapCavalier, cool to know people appreciate it :)

Answer (score 5):

You mean locational damage/different hitboxes? Headshots definitely do more damage, but I'm not sure about torso/extremities. Tanks also take more damage from behind and the sides.

Comment: Locational damage, yes, that's the word =)

Answer (score 3):

As the answers are outdated, I think it can be necessary to provide an update for future readers.

Shooting the torso will do normal damages (as you can see in the weapons stats).
Shooting the arms or legs will reduce the damages.
Now when shooting the head, the rules are:

- Every standard weapon has a **2x headshot multiplier**.
- The sniper rifles have a **2.1x headshot multiplier**.
- Some special weapons break these rules (For example, the Daimyo has a **4x headshot multiplier**)

Comment: A discussion about whether code tags are allowed as a stylistic choice has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98852/discussion-on-answer-by-fareanor-does-it-matter-where-your-shots-land-in-planets).

Answer (score 2):

It depends what kind of weapon you are using. Most infantry weapons do bonus damage when they hit the player's head hit box. Different types of infantry weapons do different amounts of bonus damage.

To my knowledge, none of the weapons on vehicles or aircraft do bonus head shot damage.

I thought this [PS2 Weapon Data Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AuOojvNLMApVdEtIU1NKenEzNzZOSWNaanFqSUVxLWc&gid=62) has the exact modifier for each weapon, but I can't seem to find it anymore...

From memory (this may have changed or I could be totally wrong)

- Sniper rifles do a 2x bonus damage modifier on head shots
- Rifles do 1.5x damage modifier
- shotguns do 1.25x damage modifier
- Mini-Chaingun does **no** bonus damage.

Comment: Vehicle weapons ARE able to do headshots. I've done quite a few headshots with my AP Vanguard.

Comment: @dbemerlin I agree that you can hit a player's head using vehicle weapons. However, I do not think it does any bonus damage. If you can link a source that indicates otherwise, I will change my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, headshots do more damage. With the bolt action sniper rifles a headshot is an instant kill (most of the time). You always need to aim for the head. If you get a kill headshot you also gain 10xp more. But there are a few things to note.

Some weapons might have 0% headshot bonusdamage multiplier and others might have 200%.

http://www.planetside-universe.com/news-clarification-on-headshots-2507.htm

Comment: "0% headshot damage multiplier" - you mean they do no damage at all if you hit them in the head? :S

Comment: @Ian No it means it just does normal damage -> 100damage + 100damage * 0/100 is still 100 damage

Comment: it's quite misleading as it's currently written. A zero multiplier implies that the end result is zero, you don't mention that you're treating headshot damage as additive (is it actually additive in PS2?). It would be clearer as "Some weapons might do no additional damage on a headshot, whilst others might deal as much as 3x normal." Or something like that. 1x - 3x multiplier is easier to understand than 0x - 2x on an additive value that is the same as base value.

Comment: That source is pretty outdated. It's a statement by a developer during development, and ends with the disclaimer ***"Exact balance for this is not final, but that's the general idea that we're going with and we'll tweak as necessary."***, so it should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Philipp The question is does it matter where you hit? And it does for the head....